# How to change menu hover text colour?

Tags: 12.04, gtk

I have taken a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/113034/gtk-theme-change-menu-bar-hover-color but it doesn't seem to work on 12.04, nor can I find those lines in 12.04.

My menus look like the below when hovered over for some applications such as Eclipse, Pidgin, LibreOffice etc.

[image]

[image]

Where as it looks much better on Nautilus and a few others.

[image]

How to change the text colour on hover to white?

**Edit:**

I use Cinnamon with Ambiance theme

Comment: @vasa1 Agreed, added details now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to answer this although I don't use Cinnamon. I'm running Xfce 4.10 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I can edit the theme's `gtkrc` file (in the `gtk-2.0` folder) in two ways.

First, I can enhance contrast between text and background by modifying `bg[SELECTED]`: the example uses "yellow" instead of `selected_bg_color`.

> style "menu"
>
> {
>
> ythickness        = 3
>
> xthickness        = 0
>
> GtkMenuBar  :: shadow-type      = GTK_SHADOW_NONE
>
> **bg[SELECTED]**      = "yellow" #@selected_bg_color
>
> bg[NORMAL]        = shade (1.18, @bg_color)
>
> bg[PRELIGHT]      = @selected_bg_color
>
> bg[ACTIVE]        = shade (1.18, @bg_color)
>
> bg[INSENSITIVE]   = shade (1.18, @bg_color)
>
> fg[NORMAL]        = @fg_color
>
> fg[PRELIGHT]      = @base_color
>
> fg[SELECTED]      = @base_color
>
> fg[ACTIVE]        = @base_color

The result is here:

[image: modified background]

Alternatively, I can enhance contrast by modifying `fg[PRELIGHT]`: the next example uses "green" instead of `base_color`.

> style "menu"
>
> {
>
> ythickness        = 3
>
> xthickness        = 0
>
> GtkMenuBar  :: shadow-type      = GTK_SHADOW_NONE
>
> bg[SELECTED]      = @selected_bg_color
>
> bg[NORMAL]        = shade (1.18, @bg_color)
>
> bg[PRELIGHT]      = @selected_bg_color
>
> bg[ACTIVE]        = shade (1.18, @bg_color)
>
> bg[INSENSITIVE]   = shade (1.18, @bg_color)
>
> fg[NORMAL]        = @fg_color
>
> **fg[PRELIGHT]**      = "green" #@base_color
>
> fg[SELECTED]      = @base_color
>
> fg[ACTIVE]        = @base_color

[image: Modified text]

If you prefer the same colors as used by your current theme, you could consider using `shade` to brighten or darken text or background. Higher values brighten, lower values darken.

Comment: That was it! I added `fg[PRELIGHT] = "white"` to `style "menu"` and the menus look much better now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's a little bit more... You can make the change you want to the theme system-wide (in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance`) or after making a copy of it in `~/.themes/Ambiance`. In the latter case, the change won't be lost when the theme is updated.

Comment: Makes sense. I have made quite a few changes at `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance` already. Better back it up before I lose it later. Also, following the same technique I even changed the scrollbar colours. It now looks clearly distinguishable.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I rename the theme to MyAmbiance when I move it over to ~/.themes.

Comment: Yes, I concur...